# JPanel in a cell of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How could I put a `JPanel` into a cell of a `JTable`?
(There would be a column what would contain `String` objects, and an other column with `JPanel` objects. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Read the part that talks about using Custom Renderers. The ColorRenderer example puts a JLabel in a cell. You could easily change that to use a JLabel instead.

Comment: Now, I've successfully added a `JPanel` with a `JButton` to the cell, but only the upper-half of the button is visible, and if I click on the cell, it does nothing. Is it possible to make the button on the panel "clickable"?

Comment: can't you just add an ActionListener to the button? But I guess you will need to pass in the table's row, column info to the listener as well

Comment: I do not believe that you can actually interact with a JPanel inside of a table cell doing this. If I am wrong please let me know, because I am trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @user489041 hah? Is that true??  Impossible to interact with the component inside of the jpanel (within the JTable cell)...??

Comment: @gumuruh I believe so. Its been a while since I attempted this. I think it just uses an image of the panel and its contents.

Comment: @user489041 but now i'm trying to do what they mentioned about applying a jpanel inside cell's jtable... Loook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923089/swing-jtable-custom-rendering

But, I agree that this is quite complex things to do.

Comment: @gumuruh In all honesty, I found it easier to just create my own table class. I just used JPanels as cells, and a GridLayout to organize them. Worked out pretty well and allowed for the all contents in the cells to be interactive. If I have time later, ill see if I can dig it up.

Comment: You won't success trying to interact with renderers. You need to interact with editors instead. Read the JTable documentation about that. I'm finishing a project that uses a table with differents editors/renderers, as soon as I have the code finished I will post that up.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that by adding an editor to the data type that the panel covers