# How to create a custom JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

I am making a chat application in Java. They can add friends and chat with them.

Here is my add friend `JFrame` idea:

[image]

I tried to google search `Multi jpanel in one jscrollpane` but I found nothing. I ended up with custom `JTable`. I want to create a custom `JTable` which have `JLabel`s in different position in each slot. Users can just select a slot in `JTable`, then they can use the `JButton` below to chat with them.

Is it possible to do this in Java. Is yes, please share your idea. Thanks.

Comment: Read about [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). `getTableCellRendererComponent` can return any Component, even a Container.

Comment: Agree with @PeterMmm you will need to have a look at how to customise your rendering for each cell.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036036/adding-multiple-jprogressbar-to-tablecolumn-of-jtable) is a post which adds `ProgressBar`s to table cells

Comment: @PeterMmm Include JPanel?

Comment: JPanel extends JComponent, JComponent extends Container, Container extends Component, yes.

Comment: @PeterMmm I tried some code from Google. The result is like `Lnsdf@19839`

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it. It was about a month ago. I was making another similar application

Comment: @Jeremy You are rigth the `JPanel` will be the solution. [Here is a stackoverflow post adding a JPanel to a JTable cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795695/jpanel-in-a-cell-of-a-jtable)

Comment: @isi I read about that before. But it is `JLabel` not `JPanel` :(

Comment: @Jeremy I have transfered the code using the `JLabel` into now using a `JPanel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely different approach using neither a table nor a list. It uses panels as items arranged as a list inside of another panel. This solution doesn't requires any further modification to delegate any events to the underlying controls. The events are processed natively. The idea comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616065/3165552). I have separated the logic into two parts for now.

[image: List of <code>JPanels</code> arranged inside on a `JPanel] [image: smaller resized version]

### JPanelList class

This class is a `JPanel` and maintains a list of such. ATM they can be added using the methods `addPanel` and `addPanels`.

```
public class JPanelList extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel mainList;
    private List<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    public JPanelList() { this(new ArrayList<JPanel>()); }
    public JPanelList(List<JPanel> panels) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainList = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        mainList.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
        add(new JScrollPane(mainList));
        addPanels(panels);
    }
    public void addPanels(List<JPanel> panels) {
        for (JPanel panel : panels)
            addPanel(panel);
    }
    public void addPanel(JPanel panel) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainList.add(panel, gbc, 0);
        panels.add(panel);
        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

### JListFrame test class with main function

```
public class JPanelListFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JPanelListFrame window = new JPanelListFrame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public JPanelListFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 210, 192);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JPanelList panelList = new JPanelList();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton btnAddMypanel = new JButton("Add MyPanel");
        btnAddMypanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // just add a MyPanel with a Value containing a
                // "asdf" and a random boolean
                panelList.addPanel(new MyPanel(new Value("asdf",
                        (int) (2 * Math.random()) % 2 == 0)));
            }
        });
        panelList.add(btnAddMypanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

One drawback with this solution is that the selection mechanics are lost. When selecting elements is a key requirement maybe a `JList` might be more appropriate. Another thing is that the items are not rendered as they would be rendered inside a `JList` or `JTable` e.g. using fancy borders. This can be solved by somehow adding a border decorator before adding the panels into the `mainList` of the `JPanelList`.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, the scrollpane will justify the scrollbars. But if you want the inner panels to fill the whole space in terms of width some extra effort will be necessary. I added a picture of the actual behaviour when resizing the whole window to be smaller than the inner panels

Comment: Thanks :D (character limit)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. But it contains some flaws yet

- Size propagation is fiexed (may be better client or server based sizing)
- No event delegation to underlying `Component`
- Performance, because heavyweight panel instances are created frequently inside paint loop

But here is how it can be done. The code is separated into parts.

### A value class

Just a simple class to represent the date inside your panels for each cell.

```
class Value {
    public final String text;
    public final boolean flag;
    public Value(String text, boolean flag) {
        this.text = text;
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

### My individual panel class

The representation can be modelled within a gui editor like google's window builder. This panel makes use of the value and displays it accordingly.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel(Value v) {
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(v.text);
        add(lblNewLabel);
        JCheckBox chckbxSomeValue = new JCheckBox("some value");
        chckbxSomeValue.setSelected(v.flag);
        add(chckbxSomeValue);
    }
}
```

### A table cell renderer class

Just returns some panel instance showing up the desired values.

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

class MyPanelCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        return new MyPanel((Value)value); // maybe performance problem
    }   
}
```

### A custom table model

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public MyTableModel() {
        super(new Object[][] {
                        new Object[] { 1, new Value("asdf", true) },
                        new Object[] { 2, new Value("qwer", false) } },
                        new String[] {"Id", "MyPanel" });
    }

    Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { Integer.class, Value.class };

    MyTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
        super(data, columnNames);
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnTypes[columnIndex];
    }
}
```

### A frame class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MyFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    public MyFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new MyTableModel());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getColumnModel()
            .getColumn(1)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyPanelCellRenderer());
        table.setRowHeight(40); // static sizing

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

### Main Function

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame window = new MyFrame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### The final result

[image: The result]

The panel `MyPanel` is created using eclipse and google's window builder

[image: <code>MyPanel</code> creation]

Comment: Wow thanks. I just need to replace `MyPanel` with my own right?
The friends name is stored in client's computer. Is it possible to set the text of `JLabel` after client got the data from server?

Comment: @Jeremy #1 Yes in theory you just need to replace the panel type `MyPanel` to your panel type. But as i said the solution still has some flaws. #2 You can modify the panel class to take appropriate setters for setting the values afterwards.

Comment: @Jeremy after all i ask myself, do you really need a table?? isnt it the fact that you just have a list of items with individual panels associated? Or do you need the columns of the table for some reason? If not think about using a JList instead ;)

Comment: I want the result look exactly like http://i.stack.imgur.com/mm1VN.png . I think the only solution is, `JTable`. :3

Comment: @Jeremy But you are not using any Columns in that picture. E.g. in my implementation there are two columns one for the "Id" of the row and another one for the panel called "MyPanel". So if you dont need the columns then it is also managable by a list or am i wrong with that??

Comment: Yes you are right. I only need one coloumn. Is it possible with `JList`?